# Winrt Xaml Toolkit bind to sub property of control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I'm doing a custom `PieChart` with the Winrt Xaml Toolkit and I'm having difficulty binding to a property of my main element. Here's the code:

```
<Charting:Chart x:Name="PieChart" Title="Pie Title" Width="300" Height="300">
    <Charting:Chart.Series>
        <Charting:PieSeries Title="Population" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Amount}" IsSelectionEnabled="False" Width="125" Height="125" />
    </Charting:Chart.Series>
    <Charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
        <Style TargetType="datavis:Legend">
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" xmlns:series="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="series:LegendItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="series:LegendItem">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Amount}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
</Charting:Chart>
```

In my `LegendItem` I have a `TextBlock` to which I want to bind the `DependentValueBinding` property from my `Charting:PieSeries` element. How can I do this? I also tried referencing the element `Self` but cannot get the sub properties.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the `Name` of your `PieSeries` and bind by `ElementName`?

Sample fragment of your code below:

```
  <Charting:Chart.Series>
    <Charting:PieSeries x:Name="MySeries" Title="Population" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Amount}" IsSelectionEnabled="False" Width="125" Height="125" />
  </Charting:Chart.Series>


  <ControlTemplate TargetType="series:LegendItem">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DependentValueBinding, ElementName=MySeries}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I think it's almost there, it prints me a string with `Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.Binding`. I'm trying several properties of that element, but so far I only managed to get the Binding name, i.e., `Amount.`

Comment: Sorry, DependentValueBinding is type of Binding so you can't do this by ElementName. 
Can you show me how do you set ItemsSource or add items to your pie series? Does your chart show series? A screenshot of your current progress will be useful.

Comment: You can take a look at what you asked here: [http://pasteboard.co/19QoBKn7.png](http://pasteboard.co/19QoBKn7.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you debug the visual tree of a PieSeries - you'll see that the `DataContext` of a `LegendItem` is a `PieDataPoint` and not your item, so it won't have an `Amount` property. The `Title` element also has `PieDataPoint` as the `DataContext`, but the `Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"` part makes the `DataContext` of its `ContentPresenter` be your item. Perhaps then you could make it work by doing this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <datavis:Title Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
    <TextBlock DataContext="{TemplateBinding Content}" Text="{Binding Amount}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: It makes sense, but does not work. `Amount` property not found.

Comment: If I do this: `DataContext="{TemplateBinding Content}" Text="{Binding DependentValue}"` I get the value `0`, so I think I'm just missing the correct `DataContext`.